# Anchor on Android Phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

Having troubles with a Back to Top button on android.  This is working on all browswers, IOS, Mac and Windows, but not Android (Ice Cream).  The button is appearing but is not staying in it's fixed position.

CSS:

```
#TopButton {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    color: #b5b5b5;
    left: 55%;
    bottom: 8%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#TopButton").hide();
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#TopButton').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#TopButton').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#TopButton').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: What's the point of `float: left;` when you have a fixed element?

Comment: Whoops, that was left over from before. *Fixed

Comment: Nope, still not scrolling with the screen.